# "as nossas vidas juntas" ou "as nossas vidas juntos"?

Tags: concordância-nominal

Uma antiga composição da MPB, da autoria de Antonio Maria, tem o seguinte trecho:

> Porque você me olha
>   Com esses olhos de loucura?
>   Por que você diz meu nome?
>   Por que você me procura?
>   **Se as nossas vidas juntas**
>   Terão sempre triste fim
>   Existe um preconceito muito forte,
>   Separando você de mim.  ------------------- [**Preconceito**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZ4GuMxMUhY)

A minha pergunta é sobre a concordância nominal.  No caso de Maria estar dizendo "as nossas vidas juntas" à Júlia, eu não tenho dúvidas, o adjetivo (juntas) tem que ser no feminino/plural.  Mas se Pedro diz a mesma coisa a Maria?  A concordância deve ser "as nossas vidas juntas", "as nossas vidas juntos", ou estariam ambas gramaticalmente corretas?  Caso ambas as formas estejam corretas, haveria alguma diferença semântica - mesmo que sutil - entre as duas formas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texto poético inevitavelmente deixa mais espaço para interpretação, mas eu diria que deve ser escrito como está no original, concordando `juntas` com `vidas`, "as nossas vidas juntas", pois são duas vidas que, quando juntas, terão um triste fim.

Talvez seja possível usar `juntos` se uma das personagens for masculina, mas seria necessária uma vírgula: "as nossas vidas, juntos", deixando implícito algo como "as nossas vidas, [se estivermos] juntos". Me parece OK para uma poesia, mas talvez não tão bom como letra de música.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bem esclarecedora.

Answer (score 2):

"As nossas vidas, juntas, durariam cento e cinquenta anos."

Quem está junto são as nossas vidas.

Um poderia estar na Lapônia e outro no Chaco.

"A nossa vida, juntos, durou quinze anos."

Quem está junto somos nós (nossa vida juntos durou quinze anos, depois cada um foi para o seu lado e viveu mais quarenta anos).

No caso, talvez fosse melhor "a nossa vida juntos". Mas aí tem um problema no verso seguinte, que teria de mudar para "Terá sempre triste fim", e o que o autor provavelmente quer dizer, no contexto, não é que haveria uma triste separação, mas duas tristes mortes...

Answer (score 0):

A sentença correta é "Se as nossas vidas juntas", é um caso de concordância nominal, portanto deve concordar com o substantivo "vidas"